# Iterating over a list of strings in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, loops

I'm trying to iterate over a list of strings in MATLAB. The problem is that, inside the 'for' loop, my iterator is considered a 'cell' rather than a string.

```
for str = {'aaa','bbb'}
  fprintf('%s\n',str);
end

??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

What is the correct\elegant way to fix this?

Comment: I wonder if this is a conceptual bug in MATLAB's design. Why is this built like this?

Comment: @Memming Nope. Just someone who doesn't know how to use the `*printf` family of functions

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should call the cell's content via `str{1}` as follows to make it correct:

```
for str = {'aaa','bbb'}
  fprintf('%s\n',str{1});
end
```

Here's a [more sophisticated example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-15544.html#br2ypq2-1) on printing contents of cell arrays.

Comment: `char(str)` works too, and doesn't fail if the loop is changed so that str comes in as a char array rather than a cell

Comment: This really bothers me every time I work with a cell array of strings. Isn't there a more elegant way to iterate over the cell array of strings to directly getting the cells content without calling str{1}? -- edit -- 
nevermind, just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587564/can-the-s1-annoyance-when-iterating-over-a-cell-array-be-avoided

Answer (score 6):

```
str={'aaa','bbb'};
fprintf('%s\n',str{:});
```

No need for `for` loops.

EDIT:
See also: `cellfun`

Comment: @petrichor I code matlab for a living at the moment. I have been hock deep in `cellfun` and repetitive calls like this. I've also learned the One True Rule about matlab: never use looping. Even a godawful mess of `repmat`, `permute`, and `reshape` is faster than iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with R2016b you can use [string arrays](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html):

```
for str = ["aaa" "bbb"]
  fprintf('%s\n',str);
end
```