# Matlab strcat does not return a string?

Tags: string, matlab

imgstr can't recognize the output string from strcat.

```
homedir = 'C:\Users\...\images\';
for img = {'01.bmp', '02.bmp', '03.bmp'}
  imgstr = strcat(homedir, img)
  I = imread(imgstr);
end;
```

outputs:

```
imgstr = 'C:\Users...\images\01.bmp'
Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 477)
The filename or url argument must be a string.
```

strcat should be returning a string, not a char array, since my inputs are strings. Shouldn't it?

Comment: It looks like this has now been fixed, in Matlab 2016b this appears to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is with how MATLAB iterates over cell arrays.  [Here's a related question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687611/iterating-over-a-list-of-strings-in-matlab)

Inside the loop add a `{1}` to extract the char array, and it should work:

```
imgstr = strcat(homedir, img{1})
```