# why strcat() doesn't return a string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to access multiple files in a for loop, like this:

age = xlsread(strcat('Pipeline_BO_2013_',names(2),'_CDBU.xlsx'), 'Data', 'H:I')

It returns an error the filename must be string. So I did following test:

> > filename = strcat('Pipeline_BO_2013_',names(2),'_CDBU.xlsx')

filename =

```
'Pipeline_BO_2013_0107_CDBU.xlsx'
```

> > isstr(filename)

ans =

```
 0
```

This is so weird. Could any one help me out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try `ischar` and let me know what results you get. According to the MATLAB documentation `isstr` will be removed in future releases. BTW, if I copy and paste your input I get `ans=1` for `isstr(filename)` .

Comment: Try `ischar(names(2))`. I'm betting that will return `0`. If it does, try using the following to create the filename: `filename = ['Pipeline_BO_2013_', num2str(names(2)), '_CDBU.xlsx']`. Let me know if it works and I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: Matlab `isstr` is functionally identical to `ischar`; it's just a name change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab strcat does not return a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532603/matlab-strcat-does-not-return-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `names` is a `cellstr` and not a `char` array. If so, indexing in to it with parentheses like `names(2)` will return a 1-long cellstr array, not a char array. And when `strcat` is called with any of its arguments as a cellstr, it returns a cellstr. Then `xlsread` errors because it wants a `char`, not a `cellstr`.

Instead of just calling `isstr` or `ischar` on `filename`, do `class(filename)` and it'll tell you what it is.

Another clue is that `filename` is displayed with quotes. This is how cellstrs are displayed. If it were a char array, it would be displayed without quotes.

If this is the case, and `names` is a cellstr, you need to use `{}` indexing to "pop out" the cell contents.

```
filename = strcat('Pipeline_BO_2013_',names{2},'_CDBU.xlsx')
```

Or you can use `sprintf`, which you may find more readable, and will be more flexible once you start interpolating multiple arguments of different types.

```
filename = sprintf('Pipeline_BO_2013_%s_CDBU.xlsx', names{2})
% An example of more flexibility:
year = 2013;
filename = sprintf('Pipeline_BO_%04d_%s_CDBU.xlsx', year, names{2})
```