# Can the "s{1} annoyance" when iterating over a cell array be avoided?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

The "`s{1}` annoyance" of the title refers to the first line within the for-block below:

```
for s = some_cell_array
    s = s{1};  % unpeel the enclosing cell
    % do stuff with s
end
```

This `s = s{1}` business is necessary because the iteration over `some_cell_array` does not really iterate over the contents of `some_cell_array`, but rather over 1-element *cells*, each containing an item from `some_cell_array`.

Putting aside the question of who could *possibly* want this behavior as the *default*, is there any way to iterate over the *bare* contents of `some_cell_array`?

Comment: I would like NOT to put aside the question of "who could possibly want this behavior"! @#$% Matlab - why? any ideas are most welcome.

Comment: @Shai (don't get me started...) ;-)

Comment: No answer for you, but I find it aesthetically slightly less annoying to use `s{:}` rather than `s{1}`, for some reason.

Comment: Also: what I find more annoying is that you can't use `for s = some_cell_array{:}`. That would be quite a nice syntax. Unfortunately, `FOR expression comma separated list must have exactly one item.`

Comment: @Shai: I think it's default to stay consistent with how for loops work for regular arrays (Matlab loops over dimension 2). In order to be able to loop over dimension 2 of a *cell array*, the loop variable necessarily has to be a cell array as well. Hurray for consistency, but I think most users work around it more often than use it as intended.

Comment: I would go with `for ii = 1:numel(someCellArray); % do something with someCellArray{ii}; end`, should even be more performant both time and memory wise.

Comment: Minor correction: "but rather over 1-element cells" -- to be exact, `for` loops over cell array _columns_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to avoid this problem in the general case. But there is a way if your cell array has all numbers or all chars. You can convert to an array and let the `for` loop iterate over that.

For example, this:

```
some_cell_array = {1,2,3}
for s = [some_cell_array{:}] % convert to array
    s
end
```

Gives:

```
s =
     1
s =
     2
s =
     3
```

Another option is to create a function that operates on every cell of the array. Then you can simply call [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and not have a loop at all.

I don't have any ideas about who would want this behavior or how it could be useful. My guess as to why it works this way, however, is that it's an implementation thing. This way the loop iterator doesn't change type on different iterations. It is a cell every time, even if the contents of that cell are different types.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the contents of `some_cell_array` are strings.

Comment: @H.Muster I did not claim that it would work for strings, only chars. Something like `{'a','b','c'}`.

Comment: @shoelzer: No you did not and I did not want to blame you for it, i.e., no offense intended. I just wanted to note the fact.

Comment: @H.Muster None taken! The reason it doesn't work for strings is that all strings will be concatenated into a single string and the loop will iterate over each char individually. For example, `[{'a', 'bb', 'c'}]` gives `'abbc'`

Answer (score 4):

Just a small add-on to Sam Robert's comment to the original question, on why you should prefer `s{:}` over `s{1}` : easier bug tracking.

Imagine you mistakenly stored your cell `s` as a *column* instead of a *line*. Then

```
for s = some_cell_array
```

will simply return a cell `s` which is *equal* to `some_cell_array`. Then the syntax `s{1}` will return the first element of `some_cell_array`, whereas `s{:}` will produce a list of all elements in `some_cell_array`. This second case will much more surely lead to an execution error in the following code. Whereas the first case could sometimes create a hard bug to detect.